# Calendar using Ajax toolkit

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to implement a calendar in my ASP.NET web page using AJAX toolkit in JavaScript for creating dynamically textbox and populate it with popup calendar. The code is as follows:

```
for(var j=1; j<2;j++)
{
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <input type="text" ID="startDate"+j runat="server" BackColor="#D6E4ED" 
        BorderStyle="Inset" Width="10px" ></input>
    <asp:CalendarExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="startDate"+j> 

}
```

After viewing in browser its giving the following error:

> The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load,
>   PreRender or Unload phases.  Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or    Unload phases.
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. 
Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): The control collection cannot be modified
>   during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases.]
>   System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child) +8677431
>   AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptObjectBuilder.RegisterCssReferences(Control
>   control) in
>   C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ScriptObjectBuilder.cs:323
>   AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs:305
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>       +627

Please suggest something to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See if you are trying to write a code block in your masterpage head <%  %>. This was the answer to my same problem.